# Trouble with positioning elements

Tags: html, css

In my page i'm having trouble with getting the right position with my element outside of the header div. I want it to automatically position after/below the div not inside it.

I guess that the "position: fixed" is ruining the document flow, is there any way around that so i don't need to use it? The Reason i use it is because i want  a header background image.

I feel really stupid not solving this on my own.

Can i get your help?

HTML and CSS CODE:

```css
.header {
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 50%;
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 z-index: -1;

}

.pic1 {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: -1;

}

.menu {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 10px;
} 

.font {
 color: gray;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 20px;

h1 {
 color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
  <title>Gesällprov</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
  <div class="header">
   <div class="menu">
    <a class="font" style="margin-right:30px" href="">HOME</a>
    <a class="font" style="margin-right:30px" href="">SHOP</a>
    <a class="font" style="margin-right:30px" href="">ABOUT US</a>
    <a class="font" style="margin-right:30px" href="">CONTACT</a>
   </div> 
   <img class="pic1" src="pic1.jpg" alt="fake.jpg"> 
  </div>
  <h1>test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think a little explanation is helpful: Putting an element after/below another element requires a defined document flow. See [Visual Formatting Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model). Positioning your `<header>` as `fixed` removes it from that normal document flow. See [position @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Effectively, there is no "after" the header because it doesn't take up any space in the document flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element `.header` has been removed *from the natural document flow*, so the space it had occupied before is no longer occupied - consider this element as no longer part of or interacting with sibling elements. This is why the `h1` element appears to be "inside" of this element, it is actually *below* it.

To resolve this common issue, you would need to account for the space (`height`) this *absolutely positioned* element *would've* taken in the DOM had it remained part of the normal document flow.

In this particular instance, this value is dynamic; the `height` of the element will vary, you will need to use *relative* length values as well (like percentage values) to offset this space.

Consider declaring `margin` or `padding` properties on the appropriate element. In this case, the better option would probably be declaring a `padding-top` property on the `body` element, e.g:

```
body {
    padding-top: 25%; /* adjust accordingly to suit requirements */
}
```

*Note: if necessary, experiment with adjusting this property value accordingly for various resolutions using `@media` queries*

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
/* Additional */
body {
    padding-top: 25%; /* adjust accordingly to suit requirements */
}

.header {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.pic1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.font {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gesällprov</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="menu">
      <a class="font" style="margin-right:30px" href="">HOME</a>
      <a class="font" style="margin-right:30px" href="">SHOP</a>
      <a class="font" style="margin-right:30px" href="">ABOUT US</a>
      <a class="font" style="margin-right:30px" href="">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
    <img class="pic1" src="https://placehold.it/800x225" alt="fake.jpg">
  </div>
  <h1>test</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just using `margin-top`

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
    margin-top:32px;
}
```